# Why is the `assets` directory *sometimes* prefixed to my `image_tag` path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've got a simple `Photo` model:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :image, :thumb, :title
end
```

and in a record view for the a particular photo, the erb:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<p><%= image_tag @photo.image if @photo.image? %></p>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_photo_path(@photo) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', photos_path %>
```

produces the following html snippet (in the body tag):

```
<p id="notice"></p>
<p><img alt="Img_8283" src="/photo/image/1/IMG_8283.JPG" /></p>
<a href="/photos/1/edit">Edit</a> |
<a href="/photos">Back</a>
```

Which is fine, because the photo is stored in `public/photo/image/1/IMG_8283.JPG`.

However, in the index view, I've got this erb code:

```
<% @photos.each do |photo| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= photo.title %></td>
    <td><%= photo.thumb %> | <%= image_tag photo.thumb if photo.thumb? %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', photo %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

which produces this html source snippet:

```
<tr>
  <td>IMG_8283.JPG</td>
  <td>photo/thumb/1/IMG_8283.JPG | <img alt="Img_8283" src="/assets/photo/thumb/1/IMG_8283.JPG" /></td>
  <td><a href="/photos/1">Show</a></td>
</tr>
```

***Why is there an `/asset` prefix in the second case and not the first?*** I would have expected the `<img>` tags to reference the same base location paths (and would be my preference too).

Answer (score 0):

In the second example, when you use `image_tag`, you are using a function from the [assets pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) to access a photo, which means that `image_tag` will append your path to `assets/`, in order to find the photo you are looking for.

However, if there is already a file in `public/assets...` it will still be served, giving you the issue with inconsistency.

Comment: err... I thought I was using `image_tag` in both cases ... but that's probably not what you were trying to differentiate.  As a best practice, what would you suggest?

Comment: alright, I didnt see that at first. Do you have an image both in the assets and public directories?

Comment: Well I didn't, but to move ahead with the rest of the design I created a softlink from `public/assets/photo/thumb -> public/photo/thumb` in the file system.

Comment: well, the issue is, if there is one already in public, it will serve that first. For example, when you first made the project, you had to delete the index page, otherwise any other index page would not show.

Comment: but, in this case, it would be that image_tag would pull from public first.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what your trying to point out.  In my `public/photo/` sub-directory, I've got (and always had) two sub-directory trees `image/<id:>` and `thumb/<id:>`.  The generated html is quite clear: it creates one link with the `asset/` prefix and one with out.  To make the index listing work, I created a softlink on the file system. I don't feel you've answered the question ...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28515/discussion-between-jamie-and-it-ninja)